# Difference between resonance and the synchronization of coupled oscillator

Tags: definition, resonance, coupled-oscillators

I was reading about phase synchronization of coupled oscillator where the oscillators are synchronized by an applied field. Now the coupled oscillators are synchronized. So my question is that what is the difference between synchronization and the resonance process of oscillators?

Comment: "coupled oscillator where the oscillators are synchronized by an applied field" Could you add some context - are these electrical circuits or masses on springs or ...? What is the applied field?

Comment: Ok, They are spin torque oscillator in a magnetic nano material where they are synchronized by Microwave signal

Comment: Is this from a journal article? Can you provide a link to the paper or s way what you're reading that prompted the question? The answer depends on whether the oscillator-oscillator interactions play a large role in the synchronization, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization is when two oscillators completely line up in phase and frequency and you can treat them as one big oscillator. Once they are synchronized, no further energy is required to keep them synchronized, assuming we're ignoring friction.

Resonance is when there is something that is adding on to the oscillator at the resonance frequency, which is dependent on the physical conditions of the oscillator. This resonance frequency is where the added energy is completely in sync with the wave, and none of it is cancelled by the wave itself. Whatever is causing resonance will need to continuously add energy to the oscillator, and the oscillator will be increasing in amplitude.

Comment: How does this distinction change for the synchronisation between uni directional coupled oscillators / forced synchronisation. 

Resonance appears to refer to an oscillator being driven by some force that transfers energy to the oscillator with a frequency that matches the oscillator's resonant frequency. 

Forced synchronisation happens when the frequency of the external stimulus is close to the driven oscillators natural frequency. Is the key distinguishing feature the fact that the resonant frequency and natural frequency are not the same thing?

Comment: I believe the natural frequency is just another name for the resonance frequency. Forced synchronization is when an external force causes synchronization. One way to do that is to cause resonance in both oscillators and force the frequency of the oscillators to that specific resonance. Note that oscillators often have multiple resonance frequencies, so the external force would find a resonance frequency that the two oscillators shared.